# Pyspark Rolling Sum based on ID, timestamp and condition

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, window-functions

I have the following pyspark dataframe

```
id  timestamp   col1
1   2022-01-01   0
1   2022-01-02   1
1   2022-01-03   1
1   2022-01-04   0
2   2022-01-01   1
2   2022-01-02   0
2   2022-01-03   1
```

I would like to get the cumulative sum of col1 for each ID and based on timestamp as an additional column and obtain something like this:

```
id  timestamp   col1  cum_sum
1   2022-01-01   0      0
1   2022-01-02   1      1
1   2022-01-03   1      2
1   2022-01-04   0      2
2   2022-01-01   1      1
2   2022-01-02   0      1
2   2022-01-03   1      2
```

Probably a Window Function can work here but I am not sure how to count only when col1 is equal to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed need a window function and a sum, the orderby on the window function is what makes it 'rolling'.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('timestamp')
df.withColumn('cum_sum', F.sum('col1').over(w)).show()

+---+----------+----+-------+
| id| timestamp|col1|cum_sum|
+---+----------+----+-------+
|  1|2022-01-01|   0|      0|
|  1|2022-01-02|   1|      1|
|  1|2022-01-03|   1|      2|
|  1|2022-01-04|   0|      2|
|  2|2022-01-01|   1|      1|
|  2|2022-01-02|   0|      1|
|  2|2022-01-03|   1|      2|
+---+----------+----+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks this works, one question, what if i want the cumulative sum to be always behind by 1. For example on the second row, when col1 = 1, instead of having the cum_sum to 1, I would like to keep it to 0 and then only increase it from 2022-01-03. So basically the third row will have cum_sum = 1 instead of 2 and all the others will also have one less in the cum sum.

Comment: If you want the whole column to be one less you can simply subtract 1 from the cum_sum column. If you want that but have the first row stay 0 then you have to write something specific to do so, for example using `when` (e.g. when x > 0 then x-1 else x).

Comment: The issue is that if I subtract 1 from the cum sum column, there will be an issue. In the example I gave when ID is equal 2 and dates are '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-02' they will both go to 0. Instead only the first should go to 0 and the second should be one. I would like the cum_sum to be "delayed"

Comment: I solved it using F.lag(1) on cum_sum